# How to remove an entry in Firebase from Ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm developing an app which uses Firebase to store some data - User ID and device token. I want to remove an entry based on the device token.

What my app does: When a user signs in, he gets a device token in Firebase, which is used to send him push notifications. However, when he signs out the device token needs to be removed from the database.

What I have tried: I know how I can retrieve the device token, but not how to remove it - I remove the whole node instead of a specific token.

This is what I have done so far:

```
removeToken() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      FCMPlugin.getToken(function (token) {
        let firestore = firebase.database().ref('/pushtokens');
        firestore.remove();
        resolve(token);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    })
    return promise;
  }
```

- I retrieve the token, which is stored in `token`
- I create a reference to the node in the database; all the token are stored under `pushtokens`
- I remove the whole node - here is my problem. Instead of removing the specific device token, I remove the whole node.